# База данных SQLite, чтение из другой таблицы

Tags: sqlite

Есть две базы данных: trade_points.db(в ней таблица points) и база данных tab3.db (c таблицей album) Как можно сделать, чтобы первое значение из столбца uid (таблицы points) заполняло первые 25 строк столбца tpuid (таблицы album ), соответственно второе следующие 25 и т.д.. А в соседний столбец merch (таблицы album) просто заносились числа: 1 в первые 25 строк,потом число 2 в следующие 25 и т.д..Код для б.д tab3:

```html
import sqlite3
import random
data = []
a=0

for _ in range(50):  
    a+=1
    uid=a
    city=0
    adress=0
    period='Еженедельно'
    merchfio=str(random.randint(1,10))
    merch=1
    tpuid=1
    data.append((uid, city, adress, period, merchfio, merch, tpuid))


conn = sqlite3.connect("tab3.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE album( UID, CITY, ADDRESS, PERIOD, MERCH_FIO, MERCH, TP_UID)""")

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO album VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", data)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте команду `ATTACH DATABASE`:

```sh
$ sqlite3 a.tmp.db
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, login TEXT);
INSERT INTO users (id, login) VALUES (1, 'ivan');
```

```sh
$ sqlite3 b.tmp.db
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE profiles (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, body TEXT);
INSERT INTO profiles (id, body) VALUES (1, 'i am ivan');
```

```sh
$ sqlite3 a.tmp.db
```

```sql
ATTACH DATABASE './b.tmp.db' AS bdb;
SELECT * FROM users JOIN bdb.profiles USING(id);
```

```
1|ivan|i am ivan
```

Документация: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html